# Loop to add multiple values ​and make the row repeat in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a list of objects by each name and a dataframe like this.(it's a big one)

Jason = ['chair','table','pencil']

Miguel = ['smartphone','cake']

Johana = ['clock','paper']

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jason |
| 2 | Miguel |
| 3 | Johana |

I would like to use a loop that allows me to obtain the following result because I have a large database in which many rows have to be added for each name index. I would like to have the following result with a loop.

| id | name | picks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jason | chair |
| 1 | Jason | table |
| 1 | Jason | pencil |
| 2 | Miguel | smartphone |
| 2 | Miguel | cake |
| 3 | Johana | clock |
| 3 | Johana | paper |

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Jason': ['chair','table','pencil'],
    'Miguel': ['smartphone','cake'],
    'Johana': ['clock','paper']
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'Jason'], [2, 'Miguel'], [3, 'Johana']], columns=['id', 'name'])

pairs = []
for i, (id_, name) in df1.iterrows():
    pairs.extend([[id_, name, k] for k in data[name]])
df = pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns=['id', 'name', 'picks'])
print(df)
```

prints

| index | id | name | picks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Jason | chair |
| 1 | 1 | Jason | table |
| 2 | 1 | Jason | pencil |
| 3 | 2 | Miguel | smartphone |
| 4 | 2 | Miguel | cake |
| 5 | 3 | Johana | clock |
| 6 | 3 | Johana | paper |